# Validate credentials for remote domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

Can anyone advise on how to validate credentials on a remote domain?

My environment has multiple domains that do not have trust relationships defined between them.
I have a Powershell script that needs to access a shared folder residing on a server in another domain which obviously requires authentication. Prior to accessing it, I need to validate credentials to avoid lock-outs (The script can be ran against multiple servers).

In the past I've used this [wonderful script](https://www.powershellbros.com/test-credentials-using-powershell-function/) which used current domain for validation but I cannot get it to work against a remote domain.
I tried this is (slightly modified script from link above):

```
function Test-Cred {
           
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])] 
       
    Param ( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory = $false, 
            ValueFromPipeLine = $true, 
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )] 
        [Alias( 
            'PSCredential'
        )] 
        [ValidateNotNull()] 
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] 
        $Credentials
    )
    $Domain = $null
    $Root = $null
    $Username = $null
    $Password = $null
      
    If($Credentials -eq $null)
    {
        Try
        {
            $Credentials = Get-Credential "domain\$env:username" -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Catch
        {
            $ErrorMsg = $_.Exception.Message
            Write-Warning "Failed to validate credentials: $ErrorMsg "
            Pause
            Break
        }
    }
      
    # Checking module
    Try
    {
        # Split username and password
        $Username = $credentials.username
        $Password = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential().password
  
        # Get Domain
        ###$Root = "LDAP://" + ([ADSI]'').distinguishedName
        $Root = "LDAP://DC=remote_domain,DC=com"      ### statically define the remote domain
        $Domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($Root,$UserName,$Password)
    }
    Catch
    {
        $_.Exception.Message
        Continue
    }
  
    If(!$domain)
    {
        Write-Warning "Something went wrong"
    }
    Else
    {
        If ($domain.name -ne $null)
        {
            return "Authenticated"
        }
        Else
        {
            $Domain    ### diagnosing the error
            return "Not authenticated"
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
format-default : The following exception occurred while retrieving member "distinguishedName": "The user name or
password is incorrect.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [format-default], ExtendedTypeSystemException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CatchFromBaseGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FormatDefaultCommand
```

The username/password is 100% correct.
Thank you

#### EDIT 1

I have found the following [blog post](http://msb365.blog/?p=1776) that goes over how to work with Active Directory using .Net assemblies. The following has worked quite well

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
#store credentials (of account with appropriate permissions)
$creds = Get-Credential 
#set the domain name
$dn = 'contoso.com' 

#Create the principal context object (so to say connect to a domain with the credentials provided)
$pc = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::`
Domain,$dn,$($creds.UserName),$($creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password))
```

I assume I could use this in an If statement to achieve what I need. Admittedly, I do not know the way of the .Net and it is a bit scary but I will have to learn it.

#### EDIT 2

Here is what I pieced together:

```
Function Test-Cred
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    [OutputType([String])] 
       
    Param ( 
        [Parameter( 
            Mandatory = $false, 
            ValueFromPipeLine = $true, 
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
        )] 
        [Alias( 
            'PSCredential'
        )] 
        [ValidateNotNull()] 
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] 
        $Credentials
    )
    
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement      

    # Checking module

    $Validated = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext]::new([System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain,'remote_domain',$($Credentials.UserName),$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password))
 
    If ($Validated.ConnectedServer)
    {
        Return "Authenticated"
    }
    Else
    {
        Return "Not authenticated"
    }
}
```

Any feedback?

#### EDIT 3

Well, EDIT 2 does not work for Powershell 4, grrr

```
Method invocation failed because [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext] dies not contain method named 'new'
```

I had to make it work like this:

```
$ContextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
$ContextName = 'target_domain.com'
$Validated = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ContextType, $ContextName, $($Credentials.UserName),$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)
```

Comment: Just a note, the first try/catch block is not needed.  Get-Credential is not validating anything.  It is only creating a credential object that holds a username string and a secure string password for later use.  It is not being tested, validated, used, etc. in that try block.

Comment: Great point! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my final version of this test function that works with Powershell version older than 5.1.

```
Function Test-Cred
    {
        [CmdletBinding()]
        [OutputType([String])] 
           
        Param ( 
            [Parameter( 
                Mandatory = $false, 
                ValueFromPipeLine = $true, 
                ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true
            )] 
            [Alias( 
                'PSCredential'
            )] 
            [ValidateNotNull()] 
            [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
            [System.Management.Automation.Credential()] 
            $Credentials
        )
        
        # Checking module
        
        Add-Type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement      

        $ContextType = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
        $ContextName = 'remote_domain.com'
        $Validated = New-Object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext -ArgumentList $ContextType, $ContextName, $($Credentials.UserName),$($Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password)       
        If ($Validated.ConnectedServer)
        {
            Return "Authenticated"
        }
        Else
        {
            Return "Not authenticated"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Norski , Did you find the c# equivalent one. And just for information. The class AccountManagement might not work with with readonly AD. in that case use DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry